# how to use a maven repo in Android?

Tags: android, maven

I am trying to extract dates from text in android and there is Java library [here](https://github.com/vbhavsingh/DateParser). However, the library needs a maven dependency as stated on the page:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>net.rationalminds</groupId>
        <artifactId>DateParser</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

I have looked at other other answers and also modified `build.gradle` in my android project as follows, but I am still not able to use the library. Can someone help me with the right usage of how to add dependencies?

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maven repo can be used in grade, the difference is the format, add code below to your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile("net.rationalminds:DateParser:1.0")
}
```